# Concourse CI job concurrency within a single pipeline

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline

I have a fairly simple terraform deployment pipeline with 4 jobs.  2 of them run `terraform apply` on commits to `UAT` and `master` branches respectively.  2 of them run `terraform plan` on PR's that target those branches.

Is there a way to configure groups of jobs to run in serial? I know I can enforce serial execution of a single job, but I want to group the *commit to branch* and *PR to branch* jobs and enforce serial execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a feature called [serial_groups](https://concourse-ci.org/jobs.html#schema.job.serial_groups) that does this. You can tag your jobs with a list of groups, and inside the pipeline, only one job with a given tag can run at a time.